How to use Azure Service Tags to only allow traffic from a specific vnet to another specific vnet?
I am looking to only allow traffic to one NSG from several specific VNets. Per the serviceTag documentation I should be able to allow it from a specific VNet but the UI does not seem to support this.

You only use Service Tags to simplify rule management and for access to or from Azure services, such as Azure Storage, Azure Database etc.
There is also no support for using VNet names.
What you need is an NSG with an Inbound Rule, specifying your comma-separated list of network addresses, applied to the VNet or subnet in question.
Let's assume you have different VNets as follows:
Name: France
Address Space: 10.1.0.0/16
Subnet 1F: 10.1.1.0/24

Name: UK
Address Space: 10.2.0.0/16
Subnet 1U: 10.2.1.0/24

Name: Germany
Address Space: 10.3.0.0/16
Subnet 1G: 10.3.1.0/24

You want servers from UK Subnet 1U and Germany Subnet 1G to be able to access a host inside the France 1F Subnet.
You would create an NSG. In the NSG, you create an Inbound security rule. For source, you specify:
10.2.1.0/24,10.3.1.0/24
Destination can be set to Any, or specify your individual host IP address.
You then assign this to your virtual network, Subnet, or virtual network interface, depending on you scope of application.
